# Why does this simple floated definition list not work in IE7, and how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

[This is a very simple `dl`](http://jsbin.com/owusu3/edit).

### HTML

```
<dl id="photo-attributes">
<dt>Edition</dt>
<dd>200</dd>
<dt>Ratio</dt>
<dd>3:1</dd>
<dt>Location</dt>
<dd>Great ocean road, Victoria</dd>
<dt>FStop</dt>
<dd>F-32</dd>
<dt>Exposure</dt>
<dd>3 minutes 40 seconds</dd>
</dl>
```

### CSS

```
#photo-attributes {
  margin: 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#photo-attributes dt {
  width: 10em;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#photo-attributes dd {
  float: left;
}
```

It works as expected in everything except IE7. The `dd` float left on one line. I can't recall what bug this is in IE7.

How do I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the [haslayout bug](http://haslayout.net/css/). But after all, the `dd` does not need to be floated left. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

IE7-specific markup (note float removed and trigger hasLayout):

```
#photo-attributes dd {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

If you remove the float for all browsers and don't trigger hasLayout for IE7, then you might not get the result you expect if the `dd` happens to have a line break/is "taller" than the `dt` to its left.

Answer (score 1):

Definition lists are sometimes a pain to figure out but i've blogged on a very simple fix which does away with floats and works in most common browsers. It involves using the `display: inline-block` style which make the element behave as an inline element but forces it to have block level styling.

http://www.qasimalyas.co.uk/definition-lists-making-them-behave/

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar and the above answers were not working. I ended up defining the  as display: block; float: none; and seemed to work fine for IE7.